# cannot ping vagrant machine

Tags: linux, vagrant

My experience with vagrant is very little as most of the time is seems to work. In this case however, I have not been able to get the desired behaviour.

I am trying to work on a rails application and it comes with its own [Vagrantfile](https://bitbucket.org/instedd/verboice/src/49eb83d3b3fe826a2402a2c46d658d674e8940c1/Vagrantfile?at=master). While I can acess the machine via ssh I am unable to ping the machine or access the rails application running on port 80 on the vm.

Btw, I am running Vagrant 1.6.3 and VirtualBox 4.1.3 on an archlinux machine.
I would really appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the `Vagrantfile`, it seems that vagrant is creating a private network, and assigning an IP to the box using DHCP.

To know which IP is using, just login on your box with `vagrant ssh` and find out the IP with the help of `ifconfig`.

You should then be able to ping the machine using that IP.

Keep in mind that you could also tell vagrant to assign a static IP to the box. Just update the `Vagrantfile` line:

```
config.vm.network :private_network, type: :dhcp
```

To:

```
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.32.10"
```

Answer (score 0):

To ping your vagrant box from your local machine, you have to enable `port-forwarding` through your `Vagrantfile`.

uncomment the following line in your Vagrantfile,

```
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
```

you can then ping vagrant box using `ping localhost:8080`

Comment: By default `vagrant` does port forwarding for `ssh`; you are forwarding host port 8080 to guest port 80, which is an addition -- not a necessity. Also unless you assign a IP address (or use DHCP) you wont be able to do ICMP ping.